# Internal Search optimization for relevance

Tags: search, optimization, solr, nlp, search-engine

My team is using Solr and I have a question regarding it.

There are some search terms which doesn't gives relevant results or results which should have been displayed. For example:

1. Searching for Macy's without the apostrophe like "Macys" doesnt give back any result for Macy's.
2. Searching for JPMorgan vs JP Morgan gives different result
3. Searching for IBM doesn't show results which contains its full name i.e International business machine.

How can we improve and optimize such cases so that it gets applied to all, even to the one we didn't catch apart from these 3 above?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these issues are related to [how you process the incoming text for those fields](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html). You'll have to create a filter chain for the field - and possibly use multiple fields for different use cases and prioritize those using `qf` - that processes the input values to do what you want.

Your first case can be solved by using a PatternReplaceFilter to remove any apostrophes - depending on your use case and tokenizer you might want to use the CharFilter version, as it processes the text before it's split into multiple tokens.

Your second case is a straight forward synonym filter or a WordDelimiterFilter, where you expand JPMorgan to "JP Morgan", or use the WordDelimiterFilter to expand case changes into separate tokens. That'll also allow you to search for `JP` and get `JPMorgan` related entries. These might have different effects on score, use `debugQuery=true` to see exactly how each term in your query contributes to the score.

The third case is in general the same as the second case. You'll have to create a decent synonym word list for the terms used, and this is usually something you build as you get feedback from your users, from existing dictionaries and from domain knowledge. There's also the option of preprocessing text using NLP, or in this case, something as primitive as indexing the initials of any capitalized words after each other could help.